# Prevent duplicate employee ids in registration SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a simple asp.net form which allow users to view a list of dates for a training and register for that date , they enter their name and employeeid manually ( i dont want to allow dulpicate employe ids), each date corresponds to a training  ( unique id in table) this gets inserted in a table with the following structure:

tbl_emptraining

```
trainig_id ( which is unique) 
trainingDate
employeename ( which is unique) 
employeeID (entered ) needs to be unique on each trainig_id and unique for all different training ids..
```

How would I prevent that a employee register for duplicate trainig ids in the Sql Database. I want to fire an event where the message can be successfully displayed to the user that the employee has been register for a training ..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should make sure the database has the correct constraints. In this case, a unique index on the employeeID field and a unique constraint on employeeName would probably be correct.

Then, in your business logic (the .net code, but it's useful to have a defined layer for this) you would make a check to the database to see if the employeeName exists already. Then return a message if the name already exists.

Finally, you could use some javascript to make an realtime call to the database in the same way as above, but this would be optional.

Also, looking at what you've written, it seems your database schema might be better with a many to one relationship between training and employees.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this off the top of my head...

Add a unique (it can be non-clustered) index on the combination of the two columns (this also makes searching by trainID/empID faster)

Use a Unique constraint (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonTrainID UNIQUE (training_id, employee_id)
```

You also mentioned that Employee Name is Unique... you may want to rethink that one... there are some very common names.

.

.

Please rate if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of SQL Server you are utilizing, you could use a [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement which will insert a record if certain criteria isn't met (commonly called an upsert statement).  If you can't utilize the merge statement, you can just write your own upsert stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

How is the user selecting the training ID?  If there is some sort of drop list, then select only those training entries for which they are eligible (there is not already a training record for that type of training and that user in the database).  Then, they won't ever select something that can't be saved.

Comment: Sorry. My issue is not with the dropdown with the training ids, that will only select the training with available sports,,,, but with the employe ids, they are entering their information for more than one training, this table is only one training name..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can set a multi-column primary key.  Use training_id and employeeID.  This will only allow employeeID "12345" to be entered once for each training_id.

Comment: I think  you should do this and also what @thursdaysgeek suggested.